# Taylor expansion $\ln(1+x+x^2)$ about $x=0$

Tags: taylor-expansion

Is it applicable to use the taylor expansion of $\ln(1+t)$ here and say $t=x+x^2 $ or do I have to take the derivatives?

Comment: It is perfectly okay to use the Taylor expansion of $log(1+t)$ in combination with $t = x + x^2$ ! This approach works well of you need only the lowest few terms of the Taylor expansion. For obtaining the full series the method is less convenient, because you will have to combine several terms in your result to find the coefficient of $x^n$.

Comment: Yes, that's fine; it amounts to repeatedly applying the chain rule (although it's easier than actually doing that).

Comment: I only had to go to $x^3$ so it worked well using $\ln(1+t)$ but I did the other method too to check

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easier way is as follows. Note that $1+x+x^2 = \dfrac{1-x^3}{1-x}$. Hence, we have
$$\ln\left(1+x+x^2\right) = \ln\left(\dfrac{1-x^3}{1-x}\right) = \ln\left(1-x^3\right) - \ln\left(1-x\right) = -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{3k}}k + \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^m}m$$
Hence, we have
$$\ln\left(1+x+x^2\right)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n x^n$$
where
$$c_n = \begin{cases} \frac1n & \text{ if $3\nmid n$}\\ -\frac2n & \text{ if $3 \mid n$}\end{cases}$$